# Как открыть ссылку, а потом сохранить ответ с сайта в переменную Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, api

Использую сервис для приема смс. Чтобы узнать баланс, используя Python, нужно перейти по ссылке, в которой содержится api ключ и команда, которая будет выполняться (в данном случае команда проверки баланса). После чего мне возвращается баланс на сайте в json формате. Выглядит так: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Больше ничего на странице нет. Можно ли как-то получить это значение сразу в переменную, без открытия браузера, без копирования html кода с сайта и вычленения баланса, и сохранить все в переменную?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сохрани в переменную адрес. Через библиотеку `requests` выполни запрос по этому адресу (смотри про http-запросы).

Её нужно установить через пакетный менеджер: `pip install requests`.

```
import requests

url = 'Тут твой адрес'

response = requests.get(url)
data = response.content
```

Полученный JSON распарсишь через стандартный json пакет в python:

```
import json

result = json.loads(data)
```

Здесь `data` - это то, что ты получил из http-запроса.
И уже из переменной `result`  вытаскивай свой баланс

Comment: responese = requests.get(url) # опечатка в имени переменной

Comment: Увидел, спасибо

Comment: @kfcgenius в переменную response будет сохранён результат запроса

Comment: @kfcgenius response это имя переменной, куда пишется ответ. Вы точно Питоном владеете? или каким-либо вообще ЯП

Comment: А, у меня опечатка) Извиняюсь

Comment: Маленькую поправку с именами переменных внёс

Comment: @kfcgenius бывает) не ошибается только тот, кто ничего не делает